# Research paper in harmonic analysis that can be read in parallel to studying the subject.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

In my idle hours I started to learn some math I touched only superficially in academia in former times. Among others I am working through the books of A. Deitmar on harmonic analysis. I've almost finished 'A First Course in Harmonic Analysis' and want to proceed with the other two ('Principles of H.A.' and 'Automorphe Formen').

Now, to motivate and to complement this attempt I wonder if there exist research papers in harmonic analysis / representation theory that are accessible by someone with math background but not an expert in in this realm.

I have no particular preferences but to narrow the scope something close to Selberg trace formula, Heisenberg group, SL(2,R) should do.

Thanks!

PS: Rather unexperienced with the MSE comments/corrections to improve the question are welcome.

Comment: You should really specify what you mean by harmonic analysis.  From the title I inferred Euclidean harmonic analysis, then you gave examples of abstract abelian ('Loomis') HA, then semisimple groups and even a unipotent group.  Harmonic analysis differs wildly among these objects.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I knew more about Harmonic Analysis I would be more precise. And yes, you are right in mentioning the rather different areas I gave as examples. At that time my main point was to find an **easy** access to some research in HA. Perhaps I should have stated that more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this expository paper](http://wumath.wustl.edu/files/math/LuthyWeissWilson.pdf) and look up the references in the section that interests you the most. It gives an overview of the connections between shift-invariant subspaces, wavelets, and sampling, and describes some very recent work on abstract harmonic analysis.